# Should all functions be fully self-contained (is it bad practice to share a variable between functions)?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, programming-practices, functional-programming

There are two ways to do the same thing (pseudo code)

1. Define databaseHandle in the parent function, and use it as a global in this scope:

   > ```
   > function API() {
   >
   >   function openDatabase() {
   >       return databaseHandle;
   >   }
   >   databaseHandle = openDatabase() 
   >
   >   function getItem(i) {
   >       databaseHandle.get(i)
   >   }
   >
   >   function addItem(name) {
   >       databaseHandle.add(name)
   >   }
   >
   > }
   > ```
2. Define a function for getting this handle, and then get it when we need it:

   > ```
   > function API() {
   >
   >   function openDatabase() {
   >       return databaseHandle;
   >   }
   >
   >
   >   function getItem(i) {
   >       databaseHandle = openDatabase()
   >       databaseHandle.get(i)
   >   }
   >
   >   function addItem(name) {
   >       databaseHandle = openDatabase()
   >       databaseHandle.add(name)
   >   }
   >
   > }
   > ```

The first option seems simpler, and I see it in many examples. But the second one seems to me more reliable and obvious in what it does (and a bit redundant).

What is the best practice here? If there's another, better way, I'd like to hear about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with the second approach, with a change which *releases* the handle when done. If each method takes care of getting, operating and releasing its own handle, then your application should be better suited to scale up (assuming you have some sort of pooling underneath).

With the first approach, it is hard to say what will happen should two different threads call each method separately at the same time.

Comment: The same problem could occur when separate threads both make calls to openDatabase and enter the critical section prior to "locking" the database handle.  Although I think the second approach is better, it really says nothing about being more thread-safe.

Comment: @Neil: The way I see it, something like that would be taken care of by the pooling mechanism, which I presume would be wrapped by the `openDatabase()`.

Comment: Meh.  I agree that this is more favorable, but there are always a thousand and one ways to do anything in a programming language.  My point was just to not mislead anyone reading your answer into thinking that the second approach is *better* for thread concurrency.  "Better" structurally perhaps, but just not more thread-safe.

Comment: @Neil: That is why I said *assuming you have some sort of pooling* underneath. If you think that this is not enough, please let me know.

Comment: But it's not better for thread concurrency *assuming you have some sort of pooling* underneath.  It would be handled by the pooling itself regardless of which approach you were using.

Comment: @Neil: But the first option uses the same handle over and over, no?

Comment: Yes of course, but so does the second.

Comment: @Neil: The second queries for a handle each time, unless I am missing something. If it queries for a handle, then the underlying pool will provide one.

Comment: Not as it is written now.  It is a pedantic point on my part, and I honestly didn't mean to offend.

Comment: @Neil: None taken :). If the question was changed then your points would be valid.